# How would you approach this design?

Tags: c#, interface

I have `ControlA` which accepts an `IInterfaceB` which has a property of type 
`List<unknownType>`

In an event of `ControlA` i need to add a new instance of `unknownType` to the List in `IInterfaceB`...

`unknownType` needs specific properties so i immediately thought it could be an interface, but quickly realised interfaces cannot be instantiated...

How would you design this system?

**EDIT** the current inheritance chain looks like this:

```
topLevelClass -> baseObject -> IBaseObject (which is implemented in topLevelClass)
```

so if i added a new class to the chain it would need to do the inheriting and implementing which would be impossible (afaik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting this correctly, you could add a constraint on unknownType to be of some interface that contains the properties you need:

```
class ControlA
{
    void Frob<T>(IInterfaceB<T> something) where T : IHasSomeProperties, new()
    {
        something.ListOfT.Add(new T() { SomeProperty = 5 });
        something.ListOfT.Add(new T() { SomeProperty = 14 });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a restriction on the type work?

```
List<T> where T : IInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

Your specification isn't specific enough to answer well, but try putting constraints on T.

```
public interface IInterfaceB<T>
    where T : new()
{
    List<T> Whatever { get; }
}
```

This allows you to do this:

```
T iDoNotCare = new T();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does List have to be an unknowntype? Why can't it be a real class, the has the real properties you need with a constructor for you to instantiate? If you need to extend that class, you can then inherit from it. Based on the information you're providing, if all you need is a few properties in the class that goes into this List, then a good old class should do the trick.